# Node redis : client cannot be created

Tags: node.js, node-redis

my node application fails to start with this error message.

```
TypeError: redisClient.on is not a function
```

RedisClient module

```
      const redisClient = require('redis').createClient({
      socket: {
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
      },
      password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
    });
        
        module.exports.redisClient = redisClient;
```

Failing block code

```
    exports.connectRedis = async () => {
      redisClient.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Connected to Redis');
      });
    
      redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error in the Redis connection:', err.message);
      });
    
      await redisClient.connect();
    };
```

Everything worked fine until (i think) i installed redis-mock.

I removed this package but it does not seems to solves the issue.

My version of redis is 4.6.4

Node is 19.1.0

Could it be a conflict ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show how you require (import) `RedisClient` file. My guess: it should be `const { redisClient } = require('RedisClient')` not `const redisClient = require('RedisClient')`

Comment: Hello @YuryTarabanko.

Same issue with this change.

Comment: Hmmm, your comment under your answer kinda contradicts the one above. Using destructuring to get `redisClient` should help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by modifying the client module to

```
module.exports = require('redis').createClient({
  socket: {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  },
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
});
```

I do not use a const anymore but cannot figure out why it fails with a const...

Comment: ok i got it i forgot to use .redisClient when importing the module

const redisClient = require('./clients/redisClient').redisClient;

instead of

const redisClient = require('./clients/redisClient');